# Remove DIVs others than clicked does not work

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to delete all divs other than clicked one using jQuery in this HTML:

```
<div id="categories-picker">
    <h2>Seleccione una categoría</h2>
    <div class="product-left" id="cstep1">
        <ul id="step1">
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="1" class="step" href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="2" class="step" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="4" class="step" href="#">Scanners</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="5" class="step" href="#">Printers</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="6" class="step" href="#">Mice and Trackballs</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="7" class="step" href="#">Mac</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="8" class="step" href="#">PC</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="9" class="step" href="#">Software</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="10" class="step" href="#">Components</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="11" class="step" href="#">Phones &amp;amp; PDAs</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="12" class="step" href="#">Desktops</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="13" class="step" href="#">MP3 Players</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="14" class="step" href="#">Laptops &amp;amp; Notebooks</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="15" class="step" href="#">Windows</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="16" class="step" href="#">Macs</a></li>
            <li><a data-resp="main" data-id="17" class="step" href="#">Tablets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="cstep2" class="product-left">
        <ul id="step2">
            <li><a href="#" data-id="3" class="step">Web Cameras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="21" class="step">Test4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="22" class="step">Test5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="cstep3" class="product-left">
        <ul id="step3">
            <li><a href="#" data-id="23" class="step">Test6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="24" class="step">Test7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="25" class="step">Test8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="26" class="step">Test9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example according to the code above if I click any `a` less say `a#data-id=1` inside the `div#cstep1` then `div#cstep2` and `div#cstep3` should be removed, if I click `a#data-id=3` then the next `div#cstep3` should be removed. Now if I click any element the `divs` should be repainted with new elements coming from `$.ajax` call. I wrote this code but it's not working since it removes all the DIVs but then I can not create anymore, it happens when I click for example any element on `div#cstep1`. Also I've tried two ways: one based on arrays and second one based on jQuery functions which generate a error. I leave boot here:

**Array version**

```
    $(function() {
        var k = 1;
        // Create the array for store every created DIV in order to 
        var divs = new Array();

        // Put the first element of the array
        divs[k - 1] = "cstep" + k;

        // Each time any a.step is clicked ...
        $("#categories-picker").on("click", "a.step", function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var resp = $(this).attr('data-resp');
            var count = $("#categories-picker > div").size();
            var parent_id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");

            // Remove elements from the array and remove divs from view
            for (var l = 0; l < divs.length; l++) {
                if (divs[l] == parent_id) {
                    for (var o = (l + 1); o < divs.length; o++) {
                        $("#" + divs[o]).remove();
                    }
                    divs.splice(l + 1, divs.length - (l + 1));
                    console.log(divs);
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id}),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.length != 0) {
                        // Add the new DIV with values after the latest DIV
                        $("#cstep" + k).after('<div class="product-left" id="cstep' + (k + 1) + '"><ul id="step' + (k + 1) + '"></ul></div>');

                        var LIs = "";
                        // Move for each JSON objects and build the elements
                        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                            $.each(value, function(i, v) {
                                LIs += '<li><a class="step" data-id="' + i + '" href="#">' + v + '</a></li>';
                            })
                        });

                        // Write the HTML to the new DIV
                        $('#step' + (k + 1)).html(LIs);

                        // Push new created DIV id in the array
                        divs[k] = "cstep" + (k + 1);

                        // Increment k value for next DIV
                        k++;
                    } else {
                        $("#categories-picker").append('<button name="next_step" id="next_step"> Continuar ...</button>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**jQuery `removeAll()` version**

```
$(function() {
        var k = 1;
        // Create the array for store every created DIV in order to 
        var divs = new Array();

        // Put the first element of the array
        divs[k - 1] = "cstep" + k;

        // Each time any a.step is clicked ...
        $("#categories-picker").on("click", "a.step", function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var resp = $(this).attr('data-resp');
            var count = $("#categories-picker > div").size();
            var parent_id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");

            // Remove all elements
            $(this).closest("div").attr("id").nextAll().remove();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id}),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.length != 0) {
                        // Add the new DIV with values after the latest DIV
                        $("#cstep" + k).after('<div class="product-left" id="cstep' + (k + 1) + '"><ul id="step' + (k + 1) + '"></ul></div>');

                        var LIs = "";
                        // Move for each JSON objects and build the elements
                        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                            $.each(value, function(i, v) {
                                LIs += '<li><a class="step" data-id="' + i + '" href="#">' + v + '</a></li>';
                            })
                        });

                        // Write the HTML to the new DIV
                        $('#step' + (k + 1)).html(LIs);

                        // Push new created DIV id in the array
                        divs[k] = "cstep" + (k + 1);

                        // Increment k value for next DIV
                        k++;
                    } else {
                        $("#categories-picker").append('<button name="next_step" id="next_step"> Continuar ...</button>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is the error generated by the second one:

> TypeError: $(...).closest(...).attr(...).nextAll is not a function
>   $(this).closest("div").attr("id").nextAll().remove();

What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: For starters you are calling methods on the return values of attr() which returns the attribute value as a string only. It is not a JQuery object.

Comment: `.attr()` returns a string, not a jQuery object, Docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you were using the return value of attr() as an object when it is just a string value.

I got it to work using this instead http://jsfiddle.net/tBCVX/:

```
$(this).closest("div[id]").nextAll().remove();
```

`div[id]` simply matches any div that has an id (regardless of the id value).

I don't have your Routing component, so it dies at that point, but the items do vanish when clicked.

*Please make any corrections to the JSFiddle version so others can play with the actual code.*

Comment: it's working by removing all the DIVs others than clicked on but when I try to click any other element inside the first DIV the `$.ajax()` call is never happen because new DIV aren't painted. As for the AJAX call feel free to change the code to paint a DIV with some values since this project is on my PC and not public

Comment: @Reynier: What new DIVs do you mean? Probably best if you explain carefully what it is intended to do. Without the Ajax call (or a suitable replacement) we have to guess a lot :)